# How do I get an out a value from an ArrayList from the user typing it in?

Tags: java

The question the user would see it "Which car would you like?" 
And I want to be able to call that specific car in the array list and have it print on one line.

I'm using an if statement so that the user types in certain letters and it will spit out the specific car from the array by itself.

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
carList.add(new Car("Nikolai", "Model S", 2017, 54999.90));
carList.add(new Car("Fourd", "Escapade", 2017, 31999.90));
carList.add(new Car("Chewie", "Corvette", 2017, 44989.90));

carList.add(new UsedCar("Hyonda", "RichardPryor", 2015, 14795.50, 35987.6));
carList.add(new UsedCar("GC", "Chirpus", 2013, 8500.00, 12345.00));
carList.add(new UsedCar("GC", "Witherell", 2016, 14450.00, 3500.3));    

String userInput = "";

for (Car theList : carList) {

    System.out.printf(theList.getMake() + "\t " + theList.getModel() + "\t " + theList.getYear() + "\t "+ "$" + theList.getPrice());    
}

System.out.println("Which car would you like? (Please type the name)");
userInput = scnr.nextLine();

if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ni")) {
    System.out.println(carList.get(0));
} else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("fo")) {
    System.out.println(carList.get(1));
} else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ch")) {
    System.out.println(carList.get(2));
} else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("hy")) {
    System.out.println(carList.get(3));
} else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("qu")) {
    System.out.println(carList.get(6));

    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("gc")) {
        System.out.println("Chripus or Witherell?");
    }
    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("chr")) {
        System.out.println(carList.get(4));
    } else
        System.out.println(carList.get(5));
}
```

I expected the System.out.println(carList.get()) to print out the corresponding array list excatly when the for loop runs. (Which I know the for loop works...)

Comment: If you want to extract an object based on a "key" input String, then best not to use an ArrayList at all, but rather use a Map of some sort, such as a `HashMap<String, Car>`. then you could get the appropriate Car easily via `map.get(keyString)`

Comment: why not use a `map` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: GMTA

Comment: Well, the instructions say to store all the care and used car instances together in the same arrayList. I just thought that since I had to use an arrayList I had to pull from it.

Comment: BTW, `} else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("qu")) {
    System.out.println(carList.get(6));

    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("gc")) {` will work work as you are not getting new input from the user

Comment: `System.out.println(carList.get(0));` - I assume that you have overriden `toString` ?

Comment: finally, retrieving based upon the `index` is not a very expandable method.

Comment: I believe so, there is an toString in the Car class

Comment: I actually don't get the weird (hash?) coding....it just prints the name of the car at best but not the entire array line.

Comment: so change the `toString` method or create a new method - anyway, what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Scary Wombat in the comments, if you really want to use `ArrayList` the easiest way is to implement/override the `toString` method. Since you say that the `toString` method currently only prints the name of the car, you can change it to something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.getMake() + "\t " + this.getModel() + "\t " + this.getYear() + "\t "+ "$" + this.getPrice();
}
```

To be even clearer, a full working `Car` might be the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Car {

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private double price;

    public Car(String make, String model, int year, double price) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return this.make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getMake() + "\t " + this.getModel() + "\t " + this.getYear() + "\t "+ "$" + this.getPrice();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        carList.add(new Car("Nikolai", "Model S", 2017, 54999.90));
        carList.add(new Car("Fourd", "Escapade", 2017, 31999.90));
        carList.add(new Car("Chewie", "Corvette", 2017, 44989.90));  

        String userInput = "";
        System.out.println("Which car would you like? (Please type the name)");
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = scnr.nextLine();

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ni")) {
            System.out.println(carList.get(0));
        } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("fo")) {
            System.out.println(carList.get(1));
        } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("ch")) {
            System.out.println(carList.get(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that `UsedCar` inherits from `Car`, you can also override the `toString` method in `UsedCar` to something like:

```
public String toString() {
    return super().toString();
}
```

This `toString` method is necessary because otherwise you are just printing the `Car` object hashcode value when you `get` it from the `ArrayList`. By overriding the `toString` method, the java compiler will call your `toString` method and print the information encapsulated in the `Car` instead. Hope that this example helps to clear things up!